# bind value to date field in aurelia

Tags: typescript, aurelia

```
            <input class="" type="date"  id="Broken" value.bind="dateval">
```

dateval is `2021-04-08T10:05:19.988Z` . How can I display a `default` date on the above `date input field` ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Value for an html date input doesn't take an iso string, so you're date will have to be in the following format 'YYYY-MM-DD'
2. Since you're value is stored in the variable dateval, you can set this variable to whatever you want when the component loads.

If you need to use an ISO string for the date, I recommend looking into value converters to get it to work. https://aurelia.io/docs/binding/value-converters#simple-converters